# millenial media ads banner tap not working in iphone and Ads pops modalview controller after 60 secs

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i 've implemented millennial media framework, it's working. but the ads pop up coming after every 60secs of timer. and i see only white banner and tap is not working. i 've implemented all delegates and banner is the superview there is no view on top of it. i want a ads banner which displays add and a Ads model to appear on clicking on it..

Your help is greatly appreciated, here is the code i 've used to add bannerview.

Thanks

// Create a 320 x 53 frame to display iPhone ads, or a 768 x 90 frame to display iPad ads
    CGRect adFrame = ((IS_IPHONE5) ? CGRectMake(0, 451, 320, 53): CGRectMake(0, 363, 320, 53));

```
// Returns an autoreleased MMAdView object
bannerAdView_ = [[MMAdView adWithFrame:adFrame
                                 type:MMBannerAdBottom
                                 apid:BANNER_APID
                             delegate:self  // Must be set, CANNOT be nil
                               loadAd:YES   // Loads an ad immediately
                           startTimer:YES] retain]; // Start timer to auto refresh the ad view
bannerAdView_.rootViewController = self; // you must set the rootViewController

[MMAdView setLogLevel: MMLOG_LEVEL_INFO | MMLOG_LEVEL_DEBUG];

[self.view addSubview:bannerAdView_];
```